# JavaScript - How to stop working of a function from another function

Tags: javascript, function

I have two jfunctions in a page,

```
function function1(){
//codes
setTimeout("function1()",5000);
}
```

and

```
function function2(){
//codes
setTimeout("function2()",5000);
}
```

functions are called when

```
<div class="navPanel">
   <div onclick="function1();">Link1</div>
   <div onclick="function2();">Link2</div>
</div>
```

I need to stop working of function1 when function2 is called and viceversa....what to do.....??? help...

Comment: Why do you need that. Are you putting the functions on the same event?

Comment: When should the function starts working again once it is stopped?

Comment: No...in two different events...

Comment: Do you want to just stop the `setTimeout()` from firing?

Comment: @ATOzTOA...yes i want that....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the timeouts to a variable which then allows you to use the [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout) function.

```
var timeout1 = {};
var timeout2 = {};

function function1(){
//codes
   if(timeout2){
      clearTimeout(timeout2);
   }
   timeout1 = setTimeout("function1()",5000);
}    

function function2(){
//codes
   if(timeout1){
       clearTimeout(timeout1);
   }
   timeout2 = setTimeout("function2()",5000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but not recommended...

```
function function1(){
    //codes
    setTimeout(function1,5000);

    function2 = function() {}
}
```

If you just want to stop the next execution of the `setTimeout` call, then just get a handle from `setTimeout` and call `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: @melpomene `"function1()"` works same as `function1` as long as you are not using `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: You should **not** be passing strings to `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist What if you want to call a function with arguments through `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Then you pass an anonymous function which calls it: `setTimeout(function() { yourFunc(arg1, arg2, ...); }, 1000);`.

Answer (score 1):

Store the return values from the `setTimeout()` calls so that you can stop them with [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout):

```
var function1Timeout,
    function2Timeout;

function function1(){
    //codes
    if(function2Timeout) clearTimeout(function2Timeout);
    function1Timeout = setTimeout(function1,5000);
}

function function2(){
    //codes
    if(function1Timeout) clearTimeout(function1Timeout);
    function2Timeout = setTimeout(function2,5000);
}
```

Note that I've changed your `setTimeout()` calls to pass *function references*, rather than strings.